# Pytest parametrized fixtures and order

Tags: function, pytest

I want to write a test that get some configuration, run a time-consuming experiment for this config (possibly in parallel), write the result to the disk or S3, run multiple tests on result for this config (see `TestIndividualResults` class below), AND THEN, a test that load all the written results for each config, and compare the results.

An example:

```py
class TestIndividualResults:

  @pytest.fixture(scope='class', params=['foo', 'bar'])
  def config(self):
    conf = ... # get some configuration stuff
    yield conf

  @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
  def result(self, config):
    data = run_experiment(config)  # time-consuming task for given config
    write(data)  # write results for this config somewhere
    yield data

  def test_check_result(self, result):
     assert len(data) > 0  # test the data associated with this specific `config`

  def test_more(self, result):
     ...
     # more tests associated with this specific `config`
     

class TestAcrossAllResults:

  @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
  def all_data(self):
    data = load_all_data()  # load all data partitions written by the multiple runs of `result` fixture
    yield all_data

  def test(self, all_data):
    assert data['foo'] == data['bar']  # compare data for config foo and config bar
```

What is the best way to achieve that? I did not manage to run TestAcrossAllResults AFTER all instances of TestIndividualResults are finished.

Comment: You could use [pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) and set `@pytest.mark.order(-1)` to the latest test. Note that this may not work if you are also [using pytest-xdist](https://pytest-order.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other_plugins.html#usage-with-pytest-xdist).

Comment: I do use pytest-xdist. But even without it, the nested parametrized fixture mess up with the order.

Comment: If this doesn't work without xdist, please write an issue in pytest-order.

Answer (score 0):

To run this parallel, make sure they run in the same process, and you can use`@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group1")` and in the command line, pass `--dist load group.` same process; y

If the time-consuming experiment depends on the parameters, consider using `async` with the tests, which could save time.

You could move `data = run_experiment(config)` inside the test itself
for example

`await data = run_experiment(config)`